# Best practice using multiple null arguments in writing R function

Tags: r

I'm writing a function that subset a dataframe based on the variables passed to it.  I read in Advanced R to use the is_null function to check for null arguments.  I've added 2 arguments which is already an if/elseif/elseif/else.  I'm afraid if I add many more of the arguments readability of the code will greatly suffer.  Is my method best practice?

```
add_scores <- function(data,
                       study = NULL,
                       therapeutic_area = NULL ){

  if (is_null(study) & is_null(therapeutic_area)){

    temp <- data 

  } else if (!is_null(study) & is_null(therapeutic_area)){

    temp <- data %>% 
      filter(BC == study)

  } else if (is_null(study) & !is_null(therapeutic_area)) {

    temp <- data %>% 
      filter(PPDDIVISIONPRI == therapeutic_area)

  } else {

    temp <- data %>% 
      filter(
        BC == study & 
        PPDDIVISIONPRI == therapeutic_area)

  }

  return(

    temp %>% 
      mutate(ENROLLMENTRANK = dense_rank(desc(ENROLLMENTRATE)),
             CYCLETIMERANK = dense_rank(CYCLETIME)*2,
             TOTALRANK = dense_rank(ENROLLMENTRANK + CYCLETIMERANK)
             ) %>% 
      arrange(TOTALRANK, ENROLLMENTRANK, CYCLETIMERANK)
        )
}
```

Comment: You’re right that usability will *greatly* suffer when you have too many such arguments. Limit them as much as possible, and instead offload the different functionality into different functions as appropriate. — Oh, and unrelated to this, `return` is unnecessary in R except to exit a function prematurely, and in your usage it negatively impacts readability.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

In your specific issue, you can separate out the `if` tests:

```
if(!is.null(study)) data <- filter(data, BC==study)

if(!is.null(therapeutic_area)) data <- filter(data, PPDDIVISIONPRI==therapeutic_area)
```

Otherwise, as you point out, the number of permutations will rapidly increase!

Comment: @dhbrand Simple typo, I fixed it.

Comment: If I replace the || 's with a single | then the function works but only when I pass all the arguments.  If I leave study or therapeutic_area as null then I get the error `Error: Result must have length 6656, not 0`.